# Is there currently a way to export cloud firestore data like we can with realtime database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In general, the way I've been thinking about setting up a test database is creating two projects for DEV and PROD. Rather than creating a custom script is there any known process for import/export for cloud Firestore?

Comment: I found this, but this is about 8 mo old...https://blog.cloudboost.io/copy-export-a-cloud-firestore-database-388cde99259b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supported export and import procedures are [documented in detail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import).  You use the gcloud command line.

> Use the firestore export command to export all the documents in your
>   database, replacing [BUCKET_NAME] with the name of your Cloud Storage
>   bucket. Add the --async flag to prevent the gcloud tool from waiting
>   for the operation to complete.
>
> ```
> gcloud alpha firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
> ```
>
> Use the firestore import command to import documents from a previous
>   export operation.
>
> ```
> gcloud alpha firestore import gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[EXPORT_PREFIX]/
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I missed this completely